# Rotate Postgres log at 5GB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to make postgres 9.1 log to have maximum size 5GB and to be circle when comes to 5GB ?
At the moment my log file is over 500GB.

/var/lib/postgres/

Comment: What postgres log are you talking about? Can you specify the file names?

Comment: Also provide your log settings. I would assume it's currently set to 500GB at minimum or you were really lucky and found a bug(not likely).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting `log_rotation_size` as described in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ROTATION-SIZE ? That would work if the log is managed directly by postgresql. If you are using syslog then you should look at newsyslog or logrotate.